# Form with Symfony 2 and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, symfony

I'm using Symfony 2 with MongoDB and I have a little problem with an embed document. In my application, I have a workout with several exercices (such as push up...)

Here is the workout document:

```
Skurty\Bundle\TestBundle\Document\Workout:
fields:
    id:
        id:  true
    date:
        type: date
embedMany:
    exercices:
      targetDocument: Skurty\Bundle\TestBundle\Document\Exercice
```

And the exercice document:

```
Skurty\Bundle\TestBundle\Document\Exercice:
fields:
    id:
        id:  true
    name:
        type: string
    reps:
        type: hash
```

For the form, I'm using 2 types:

```
class WorkoutType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('date', 'date');
        $builder->add('exercices', 'collection', array(
            'type'         => new ExerciceType(),
            'allow_add'    => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'prototype'    => true,
            'by_reference' => false
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Set default
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Skurty\Bundle\TestBundle\Document\Workout',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'workout';
    }
}
```

and

```
class ExerciceType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', 'text');
        $builder->add('reps', 'collection', array('type' => 'text'));
    }

    /**
     * Set default
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Skurty\Bundle\TestBundle\Document\Exercice'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'exercice';
    }
}
```

So in the newAction I use:

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $workout = new Workout();
    $workout->setDate(new \DateTime());

    $form = $this->createForm(new WorkoutType(), $workout);

    return $this->render('SkurtyTestBundle:Workout:new.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView(), 'workout' => $workout));
}
```

In the view:

```
<table>
    {% for exercice in form.exercices %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ form_widget(exercice) }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

And in the createAction (when the post is submitted):

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new WorkoutType());

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $workout = $form->getData();

        // ...
    }
}
```

The $form->getData() contains:

```
Skurty\Bundle\TestBundle\Document\Workout Object
(
    [id:protected] => 
    [date:protected] => DateTime Object
        (
            ...
        )
    [exercices:protected] => Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection Object
        (
            [_elements:Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection:private] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Skurty\Bundle\TestBundle\Document\Exercice Object
                        (
                            [id:protected] => 
                            [name:protected] => ...
                            [reps:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )
                        )

                    [1] => Skurty\Bundle\TestBundle\Document\Exercice Object
                        (
                            [id:protected] => 
                            [name:protected] => ...
                            [reps:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )
                        )
                )

        )

)
```

As you can see, the "reps" are empty, even if they are well submitted, here is the $request:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag Object
    (
        [parameters:protected] => Array
            (
                [workout] => Array
                    (
                        [date] => Array
                            (
                                ...
                            )
                        [exercices] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [name] => ...
                                        [reps] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => 5
                                                [1] => 5
                                                [2] => 5
                                            )

                                    )

                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [name] => ...
                                        [reps] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => 5
                                                [1] => 5
                                                [2] => 5
                                            )

                                    )
                            )
                    )

            )

    )
```

And I also have the error "This form should not contain extra fields." for each exercice.

Where is the problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should try :

```
$builder->add('reps', 'collection', array(
    'type'      => 'text',
    'allow_add' => true,
));
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked ! (and I could think about it...)